# Why the function "dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()" causes an issue in my code?

Tags: c#

I'm working in a schoolar project and am relative new  in C#, But I would like understand why this errores it happens. Thank you.

**Description of my problem:**

> I have problems when trying to remove rows of a datagridview that is already populated from a different window in an other thread. But If I dont try to import anything, dataGridView.Rows.Clear() works fine.
>
> I have two WinForms, in the first the datagridview is embeded and in the second an Excel file is imported and load at DataSource of datagridview.

**Example:**

1. When I populating manually the datagridview and then run datagridview.Rows.Clear () , it works correctly and all rows are eliminated.
   [image: first]
   [image: Second]
2. when I importing some excel file and put that information into dataSource at datagridview1, the method Clear() doesn't works and throws an Exception without additional information.
   [image: third]
   [image: quarter]

**My brief code**

This userControl is embeded in a Main WinForm.

```cs
namespace 
{
    public partial class CustomDataGridView : UserControl
    {
        private void truncateTable_tsb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("¿Do you want to delete all rows?", "Waiting confirmation...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            }
        }

        // import button shows a new winForm
        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            importWinForm = new ImportTools.Main();
            importWinForm.ParentDataGridView1 = dataGridView1;
            importWinForm.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

Import WinForm:

```cs
namespace 
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private DataGridView ParentDataGridView;

        public DataGridView ParentDataGridView1
        {
            get { return ParentDataGridView; }
            set { ParentDataGridView = value; }
        }

        private void OnUCButtonFinishClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ParentDataGridView1 != null)
            {
                ParentDataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                ParentDataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                ParentDataGridView1.DataSource = ConvertListToDataTable(Well_Data_Updated, Columns_names_updated);

                this.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you!

---

Comment: You can't add or remove rows when you use a DataSource,  You have to manipulate the DataSource or remove the DataSource itself.

Comment: Read the exception message.

Comment: you may be missing something... [The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)